# sql insert not inserting after some records

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I had been inserting successfully into database but it is not inserting anything, I did not change the code since then actually.

What can be the reason?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($new_entries)){
    $anzeigen_id = $row[0];
    $firma_id = $row[1];
    $xml_filename = "xml/".$anzeigen_id.".xml";
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->load($xml_filename);
    $value = $dom->getElementsByTagName('FormattedPositionDescription');
    foreach($value as $v){
        $text = $v->getElementsByTagName('Value');
        foreach($text as $t){
            $anzeige_txt = $t->nodeValue;
            $anzeige_txt = utf8_decode($anzeige_txt);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO testing (`firmen_id`,`anzeige_id`,`anzeige_txt`) VALUES ('$firma_id','$anzeigen_id','$anzeige_txt')";
            $sql_inserted = mysql_query($sql);
            if($sql_inserted){
                echo "'$anzeigen_id' from $xml_filename inserted<br />";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no i dont get any errors. if i check like ``echo $sql_inserted;`` i am getting nothing,

Comment: `var_dump($sql)` and test the sql directly using phpMyAdmin (for example)

Comment: ``var_dump($sql)`` is giving ``bool(false)``, so the query isnot working. but how can it be? may be there is some limit in the database for data? but i have now only 2920 rows

Comment: Are you sure you test: `var_dump($sql)`, because it must be a string, I don't ask you to `var_dump($sql_inserted);`

Comment: i am getting the whole interpreted sql statement with strings inside

Comment: What if you tried to launch this query inside phpMyAdmin now? And by the way, [you shouldn't use `mysql_` function any more](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/569101)!

Comment: in phpadmin, it is working, i am able to insert, but in the code i cannot. i think, the ``mysqli_*`` isnot the reason here

Comment: Add an `else` after the `$sql_inserted` and add this snippet to show the error from mysql: `echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error() . "\n";`

Comment: okay, this is powerful debugging: i got this with your code: 
``1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's Design, Implementierung und Integration von Fachanwendungen Entwicklung mit Hi' at line 1``

Comment: what line is this ``line 1`` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I will post an answer because it will be more clear to ask you some code example, etc..

First of all, when you got an unexplicable case like this: **you should debug!**

In your case, you display a message when the query success. But what if the query failed? You should handle an error message to see what's going on. Something like that:

```
if($sql_inserted)
{
  echo "'$anzeigen_id' from $xml_filename inserted<br />";
}
else
{
  throw new Exception(mysql_error() . '. SQL: '.$sql);
}
```

There will be an exception when a query failed. You will have the error message (`mysql_error()`) and the query that failed (`$sql`).

What could be a problem, is that you didn't escape value you put inside your query. So, if there is a `'` inside a variable, it will break the query. You should escape them:

```
$firma_id    = mysql_real_escape_string($firma_id);
$anzeigen_id = mysql_real_escape_string($anzeigen_id);
$anzeige_txt = mysql_real_escape_string($anzeige_txt);
```

So you will have a final code like this:

```
foreach($text as $t)
{
  $firma_id    = mysql_real_escape_string($firma_id);
  $anzeigen_id = mysql_real_escape_string($anzeigen_id);
  $anzeige_txt = mysql_real_escape_string(utf8_decode($t->nodeValue));

  $sql = "INSERT INTO testing (`firmen_id`,`anzeige_id`,`anzeige_txt`) VALUES ('$firma_id','$anzeigen_id','$anzeige_txt')";
  $sql_inserted = mysql_query($sql);

  if($sql_inserted)
  {
    echo "'$anzeigen_id' from $xml_filename inserted<br />";
  }
  else
  {
    throw new Exception(mysql_error() . '. SQL: '.$sql);
  }
}
```

**By the way**, as I told you [**please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 1):

The reason its not working is that you fail to sanitize the input. Consider:

```
$anzeigen_id = mysql_real_escape_string($row[0]);
$firma_id = mysql_real_escape_string($row[1]);
....
$anzeige_txt = mysql_real_escape_string(utf8_decode($t->nodeValue));
```

You should be aware of the risks of SQL injection and how to prevent it.

You should also have proper error checking in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

```
$sql = "";
$comma = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($new_entries)){
    $anzeigen_id = $row[0];
    $firma_id = $row[1];
    $xml_filename = "xml/".$anzeigen_id.".xml";
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->load($xml_filename);
    $value = $dom->getElementsByTagName('FormattedPositionDescription');
    foreach($value as $v){
        $text = $v->getElementsByTagName('Value');
        foreach($text as $t){
            $anzeige_txt = $t->nodeValue;
            $anzeige_txt = utf8_decode($anzeige_txt);
            $sql .= "$comma ('$firma_id','$anzeigen_id','$anzeige_txt')";
            $comma = ", ";

        }
    }
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO testing (`firmen_id`,`anzeige_id`,`anzeige_txt`) VALUES $sql";
$sql_inserted = mysql_query($sql);
```